# If conditionally showing, then FlatList ScrollToIndex doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I've used **Flatlist**'s `scrollToIndex` many times before but I'm developing a custom calendar and have ran into the following use case which breaks the method:

Calendar has 2 modes:

**DAY SELECTION:** Basically just a matrix of touchable days to select.
**YEAR SELECTION:** A scrollable *FlatList* with years to select from.

Only one of them must be shown at a given time.
Everything works fine **except returning the scroll position to the selected year** once I switch modes in Android (in iOS works as expected, you can check on snack example below).

Here's a little code snippet showing how I'm managing the scroll update.

```js
componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
  if (prevState.mode === TEXT_MODE && this.state.mode === LIST_MODE) {
    console.log(`updated scroll to index ${this.state.selectedItem}`);
    this.itemsScroll.current.scrollToIndex({
      animated: false,
      index: this.state.selectedItem,
      viewPosition: 0.5,
      viewOffset: 0,
    });
  }
}
```

**[HERE](https://snack.expo.io/@franch/android-flatlist-display-bug)** is a minimal working example illustrating the bug.

**NOTE:** *RN version is 0.57.1. Bug doesn't happen unless list visibility is modified.*

Comment: Could you add the entire component?

Comment: @dentemm The whole code of the component is in the MWE link https://snack.expo.io/@franch/android-flatlist-display-bug